# grails beforeDelete with many-to many relation

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm, cascading-deletes

I have 2 domain class with a many to many relationship. When I delete the entity that belongs to the other, I have to remove the relation before in order to avoid a foreign key error.

I would like to put this code in the beforeDelete event, but I obtain a problem with optimistc locking. This is the code of the domain classes:

```
class POI {

    static belongsTo = [Registration];

    static hasMany = [registrations: Registration]


    def beforeDelete = {
        def poiId = this.id
        POI.withNewSession { session ->
            def regs = Registration.withCriteria{
                pois{
                    idEq(this.id)
                }
            }

            def poi = POI.get(poiId)
                if(poi != null && regs.size() > 0){
                    regs.each{
                        it.removeFromPois(poi)
                    }
                    poi.save(flush: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


class Registration {

    static hasMany=[pois: POI];

}
```

So the relation between POI and Registration are deleted, in the beforeDelete when I call delete on an poi, but then when it tries to execute effectively the delete, I have the following error:

```
optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException:
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was 
incorrect): [ambienticwebsite.POI#22]
```

Anyone has an idea how to solve this problem by using tthe beforeDelete?

Comment: Can you try without `flushing` inside `beforeDelete`? Just use `poi.save()`.

Comment: it does not work because I obtain the foreign key error, the removeFrom is not saved to the database

Answer (score 4):

In most cases with GORM, dealing with a many-to-many relationship without manually creating a class to represent the join table creates a lot of headaches.

An example of this is the [Spring Security Core Plugin's PersonAuthority class](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/4%20Required%20and%20Optional%20Domain%20Classes.html#4.3%20PersonAuthority%20Class).

An example of many to many where deleting either end deletes the join entry as well:

```
class POI {
    def beforeDelete() {
        RegistrationPOI.withNewSession {
            def rps = RegistrationPOI.findByPOI(this)
            rps.each { it.delete(flush: true) } // flush is necessary
        }
    }

    /* example convenience method to get directly
     * from a POI to the associated Registrations */
    Collection<Registration> getRegistrations() {
        RegistrationPOI.findByPOI(this)
    }
}

class Registration {
    def beforeDelete() {
        RegistrationPOI.withNewSession {
            def rps = RegistrationPOI.findByRegistration(this)
            rps.each { it.delete(flush: true) } // flush is necessary
        }
    }
}

class RegistrationPOI {
    Registration registration
    POI poi
}
```