# Grails : delete only one side of many-to-many relation

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a many to many relation between A and B,
where A belongsTo B

Assume the following data inside the DB:

```
<a1,b1>
<a1,b2>
<a2,b1>
```

How can i delete all a1, so database will keep

```
<a2,b1>
```

in the most elegant\automatic way using mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, cascade "all-delete-orphan", which sounds very appropriate, [applies only to one-to-many relationships](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html) (I've just tested it on your scenario and it really doesn't work). I can't think of a more elegant way of handling this other than using the `beforeDelete` hibernate event on `A` to remove all the orphaned `B's`.

Consider mapping the join table as an entity as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986285/grails-beforedelete-with-many-to-many-relation) to avoid headaches and also if you need performance as suggested by Burt Beckwith [here](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance). I hate this non-Object Oriented approach but you might need to follow it. At least you'll have cascade delete.

Comment: Unfortunately , it doesn't seem possible.